# How to source from online cpp open source like github from Rstudio?

Tags: github, rcpp

I am trying to source code that exists on an online repository by:

```
Rcpp::sourceCpp(
 url("https://github.com/slwu89/MCMC/blob/master/adaptMCMC_source.cpp")
)
```

I'm encounter this issue:

> Error in dirname(file) : a character vector argument expected

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use R's `download.file()`:

```
library(Rcpp)
remurl <- "https://github.com/slwu89/MCMC/blob/master/adaptMCMC_source.cpp"
locfile <- "/tmp/mcmc.cpp"
download.file(url=remurl, destfile=locfile)
sourceCpp(locfile)   # dozens of error for _this_ file
```

*Edit* Here is a better way with *two* important fixes:

1. You need a different URL. The one you list will download the *html* page.  But you want raw source code, which in this case is `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/slwu89/MCMC/master/adaptMCMC_source.cpp`
2. You can create a simple helper function which takes the url, creates a tempfile with extension `.cpp` (hey, that argument once was my patch to base R ;-) and then returns that file name.

See below:

```
u2f <- function(url) { 
   tf <- tempfile() 
   download.file(url, tf, quiet=TRUE) 
   tf 
}
library(Rcpp)
url <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/slwu89/MCMC/master/adaptMCMC_source.cpp"
sourceCpp( u2f( url ) )
```

and that compiles fine (albeit with warnings about signed/unsigned comparison).

Comment: You are welcome. Please consider "accepting" the answer (click on the tickmark only you see as you are the one who asked the question) and maybe "upvote" the question (click on up arrow) as well.  This is how one signals a valuable answer in StackOverflow.